# phpmyadmin query vs mysql search form and special characters

Tags: php, mysql

When searching for "Loral's Library" in phpMyAdmin, then selecting "Create PHP Code" I see that the phpMyAdmin query automatically inserts the escape character for ':

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `programs` WHERE `progname` LIKE \'Loral\'\'s Library\' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

How do I include that same function in mysql search forms?

My query for such a form for "Loral's Library" would be something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE progname LIKE '$search' ORDER BY progname ASC";
```

That type search returns an error for anything with the ' character. "Loral's Library" is entered in the search form, which then passed to the search.php file to execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

```
$escapedVaue=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$originalValue);
```

That function exactly does that.

> mysqli::real_escape_string -- mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection
>
> This function is used to create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement. The given string is encoded to an escaped SQL string, taking into account the current character set of the connection.
>
> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to incorporate mysqli_real_escape_string? I know how to use it for INSERT, but not for UPDATE or SELECT.

Comment: You send all the variables to it and use its return value in your query. Like  `"SELECT * FROM yourTable where keyword='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,"test'in")."'";`

Comment: Using an html search form:
     <input type="text" name='search' size="40"/>
then processing it using php:
     $query = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE progname LIKE '$search' ORDER BY progname ASC";
and ultimately:
     $progname=mysql_result($result,$i,"progname");